# Change of variable in integration of Dirac delta function/working with differentials

Tags: integration, dirac-delta, differential

Suppose I have some quantity that is defined through the following complicated integral:
\begin{align}
A(x) = \int \delta[ f(x - y) - f(x + y) ] \, \text{d} y,
\end{align}
where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function.

Suppose we know $A_\text{nice}(x)$, assuming that $f = f_\text{nice}(q)$ is a sufficiently nice function. However, now let's say that $f(q) \not= f_\text{nice}(q)$ anymore. Luckily we do know that $f(q) = f_\text{nice}(q + \epsilon(q))$, where $\epsilon(q)$ is a small function that represents a deviation in the coordinate $q$ at which $f_\text{nice}$ is to be evaluated.

So now we have
\begin{align}
A(x) = \int \delta[ f_\text{nice}(x - y + \epsilon(x - y)) - f_\text{nice}(x + y + \epsilon(x + y))\, \text{d} y
\end{align}

Is there any nice way to at least approximate a solution to $A(x)$ such that it relates back to $A_\text{nice}(x)$?

I would imaging a possible change of variable would involve
\begin{align}
q' &= \epsilon(q) + q, \\
\Rightarrow &= dq' = 1 + \frac{\text{d} \epsilon(q)}{\text{d} q},
\end{align}
but making use of this seems unruly.

Any thoughts?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function ; The value of the integral depends on the zeros of $f(x-y) - f(x+y) = 0$ (for fixed $x$). If you can approximate them you can approximate the integral.

Comment: one zero is clearly $y=0$.

Comment: The Dirac Delta is NOT a function!

Comment: Is $\epsilon(0)=0$?